# Long query running with Memory optimized tables with daily archiving with real time data

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, bigdata, database-performance

I have a somewhat of what feels like a complex data problem that I am trying to solve. I am more a developer than a SQL expert but our DBA whom wrote the script a few months back, recently moved on and I have been tasked with resolving this problem in the short term.

I am having some real issues with four tables of which two are receiving real-time bulk inserts, being read by users and having a daily job copying then deleting the copied over records into historic tables. The operations run 24/7 and there is no downtime for the data insertions or archiving.

A script that originally did this process started to fail. It was changing the Serializable isolation from Snapshot in ReadCommitted mode, but did a full table scan so it blocked all insert operations for 1-2 hours, which was not acceptable.

**Question(s)**
The pain point for the archiving is that we have to wrap up the insert and deletes together in one transaction. Is there a better way to do the below? Is it better to not have foreign keys and use a trigger or constraint? The below scripts either lock the table too much or run for too long (1-4hours).

**Scenario**

Four SQL tables

1. Order (Memory Optimized table)
2. OrderDetail (Memory Optimized table)
3. OrderHistory (File/normal table – ColumnStore index)
4. OrderDetailHistory (File/normal table– ColumnStore index)

Order and OrderDetail tables receive on average a bulk insert between 50-700 inserts per second is performed.

Updates are only performed during the batch insert operation.

During the day the Order table can be between 3-6 million records.
The OrderDetail table can be up to 2-3 times as large as the Order table.

OrderHistory and OrderDetailHistory can have 1-7 days data, so varies between 10-50 million records at any one point.

OrderDetail has a FK reference to Order on the Id column.

At one point of time during the day, the data is copied and inserted for each table into their respective 'history' tables, which are non-memory optimized tables.

**Attempt 1**

The script with the issue does this:

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO OrderHistory
SELECT * FROM Order o 
WHERE o.CreatedAt <= 1 day

INSERT INTO OrderDetailHistory
SELECT * FROM OrderDetail od
WHERE od.CreatedAt <= 1 day

DELETE FROM Order
WHERE CreatedAt <= 1 day

DELETE FROM OrderDetail
WHERE CreatedAt <= 1 day
COMMIT
```

The database is run at Snapshot Isolation level with Read Committed.

When run, we were originally getting Serializable errors, and after some reviewing realised that the delete operation would go down to a serializable isolation level to lock the nonclustered index on the CreatedAt column whilst it performed deletes because it is doing a range scan on the index, whilst still inside the transaction that we used for selecting data too.

**Attempt 2**

So next I modified the script, by creating two memory optimized user defined tables to select data into first outside of the transaction into these udf tables. Then in a separate transaction, insert into our history table, and then finally delete in a separate transaction. The idea is that if the inserts are a success but the delete fails then the next time it runs it will not try to re-insert data twice. The downside to this is that there will be duplication in the history data until it runs again, and it ran for 2 hours before our scheduling tool timeout, so this doesn't seem ideal.

```
INSERT INTO @OrderLoadingUdfTable
SELECT * FROM Order o 
WHERE o.CreatedAt <= 1 day

INSERT INTO @OrderDetailLoadingUdfTable
SELECT * FROM OrderDetail od
WHERE od.CreatedAt <= 1 day

BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO OrderHistory
SELECT * FROM @OrderLoadingUdfTable  
WHERE CreatedAt <= 1 day
AND Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM OrderHistory)

INSERT INTO OrderDetailHistory
SELECT * FROM @OrderDetailLoadingUdfTable 
WHERE CreatedAt <= 1 day
AND Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM OrderDetailHistory)
COMMIT

BEGIN TRAN
DELETE FROM Order
WHERE CreatedAt <= 1 day

DELETE FROM OrderDetail
WHERE CreatedAt <= 1 day
COMMIT
```

Comment: Can you move the data in smaller batches? Each batch can have a transaction.

Comment: Appreciate it is a whilst since I came back to this so I do apologise! Yes in the end I went with smaller batches to reduce the locking time between transactions, if any failed it would rollback naturally. Then retry attempts would try again with the same date range thus eventually it would get through and perform as expected.